# Is it possible to make v9 ignore case when completing names?

Tags: front-end, version-9, autocomplete

In v8, I could type, say, `fulls` or `texf` to get `FullSimplify` or `TeXForm`from auto-completion. That was quite nice because I didn't need to press the Shift key for capitals. In v9, auto-completion appears only when I type `FullS` or `TeXF`, which is not so handy. Is it possible to make auto-completion ignore case?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

On my system, setting the following to `False` works (Mac OS X):

[image]

(in Preferences->Advanced->"Open Option Inspector")